# Категория выражения "красная нить"

Tags: фразеология

К какой категории вы бы отнести выражение "красная нить"? В википедии определяется как метафора. Но в самом выражении отсутствует характерное для метафоры смешивание свойства (необходимое перенесение). Мне представляется, что это фразеологизм. Я прав?

Comment: Как будто фразеологизм не может быть метафорой.

Comment: В таком случае всякий фразеологизм - метафора?

Comment: Я бы этого не сказал.

Comment: А какой фразеологизм не есть метафора?